# AlpineJS x-init being executed twice

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Below is my alpineJS template html

```
<template id="sharing" x-if="showSharing">          
      <div id="sharingContainer" x-data="preview()" x-init="getPreview()" >
        <div style="padding-top:20px" x-show="showPreview">     
            <div id="previewContent"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

Below is the code in my index.js

```
    function preview(){
      var parent=this;
      return{
        showPreview:false,
        showPicker:false,        
        getPreview:function() {
          console.log("inside get Preview");
          var self=this;
            chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function(tabs){
            let url =self.suggestUrl= tabs[0].url;
            console.log(url);  
            this.setPreviewData(url);
          });
        
        },
        setPreviewData:function(data){
          var self=this;          
          document.getElementById('container').__x.$data.isLoading = false;
          document.getElementById('sharingContainer').__x.$data.showPreview = true;
          
        }
      };
}
```

The getPreview method is being called twice.

I'm not able to figure out why.
Please Guide

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't create your `x-data` and `x-init` attributes on an element that exists inside a conditional `<template>` tag.  I'm not super familiar with Alipine, but I know that `x-data` (at least) is loaded before Alpine has finished it whole lifecycle.  This in turn would mean that it hasn't yet decided whether anything inside `<template>` actually needs to be rendered, and that in its turn could easily end with unpredictable results! Set your data on a higher level element and check if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an Alpine issue, but I'm noticing that `chrome.tabs` is returning `undefined`. When I remove that piece from the method, it runs one time.